# What subspecies of Iberian Ibex and what subspecies Golden Eagle are in this video?

Tags: species-identification

In the nature documentary El Hombre y la Tierra, there is a scene featuring golden eagles and apparently some kind of Iberian ibex. The scene should be in some part of Iberia. This is the video which features the animals and location: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yz7FFlFy8eM

Goats: [image: https://imgur.com/GKWiZPr] 
[image: 2: https://imgur.com/CTMgx9y] 
[image: https://imgur.com/l6s5Yap] 
[image: https://imgur.com/xA5y0th]

Eagle and Goats: 1: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3RHSs.jpg 2: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eBh2d.jpg Several other images: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wpare.jpg

However, these Ibex have small horns and there are none with large horns. I'm not used to seeing this with ibex. Surely it can't be a flock made entirely of females and juveniles? So I would like to ask what subspecies of Iberian Ibex these are.

I would also like to ask, if I might, what subspecies of golden eagle is shown in the clip. I suspect the one which carries off the goat will be the female of a larger subspecies.

If it is not acceptable to ask about both species, please edit the part about the eagle out of my answer. Know that I would be happy with an answer to either question. Thank you very much.

Comment: The golden eagle is just one species:  (Aquila chrysaetos) is the most widely distributed species of eagle, it's on all the northern hemisphere.

Comment: @com.prehensible My mistake, meant to say subspecies. Do you know what subspecies of aquila chrysaetos is common to Iberia, and which might be present in the video?

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! Please edit your post to include an image from the video in question — posts on this site should be stand-alone and not require users to click through to links on another site. One reason for this is that links can break (e.g. the video could be taken down) and thus reduce the value of this question and any answers. ——— Please also take the [tour] and then go through the help pages starting with [Ask] questions effectively on this site and edit your question accordingly. Thanks! 

Comment: @tyersome Thanks tyersome. I tried to add some images, but it wouldn't let me upload them from imgur.

Comment: The upload links must be to files rather than webpages — if you open the imgur images in a new tab (or window) you get a file with ".jpg" extension. I've uploaded the goat images for you, but you should probably put the eagles into a separate question.

Comment: Aquila chrysaetos homeyeri: Iberian Peninsula; nw Africa to Arabia and Iran ... don't know about the ibex, it has small deer horns?

Comment: @com.prehensible Thanks! The ibex is pretty confusing. I was wondering if it might be a different kind of goat, like some wild breed of a Spanish goat. They have horns more like that.

Answer (score 0):

The eagle is Aquila chrysaetos homeyeri or chrysaetos. Homeyeri comes from the Iberian Peninsula; nw Africa to Arabia and Iran. Chrysaetos chrysaetos comes from the Alps to Sibera and the Iberian Peninsula.

They weight up to 7kg and they can carry a bit less than 3 kilos, big prey includes baby bears, coyotes, foxes, ibex, seals, badgers, dogs, cats, they can attack anything up to 1 meter in width, generally on the neck and the back: 
[image: 0]

It can defeat anything that can't withstand the powerful talon gripping and slashing, the hullux talon is 4-6.5 cm: [image]

The Ibex subspecies is difficult to tell from the pictures,  although the ibex males and females always live in different herds and congregate once a year, all subspecies adults have horns 40-70cm in length,. The horns grow 8cm per year for 15-20 years after the first year, with females having slightly smaller horns, about 40-50cm.

The group of iberian ibex there are all 2-3 years old.

Groups of ibex entirely with small horns can be found, with other herds of ibex with 55 cm horns living elsewhere, although normally it's a bit more mixed with 4-5 year old individuals mixed in. At the time that the video was made, hunting laws were less strict than today, so it's possible that the bigger individuals of the herd had been shot.